# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: Intent in new version 4.3

Tags: android, android-intent

When i selecting the video from gallery the it gives the Security type exception. But same code working in all version of android except only 4.3. I searched the answer for same some one suggest that use  `android:exported="true"` in activity part. But still m getting same exception.

My code is

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(btngetvideo==v)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);  //<--  Here m getting exception
        }

    }


            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                    Intent resultData) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

                Log.v(TAG + ".onActivityResult", "onActivityResult call");
                try {

                    if ( resultData != null) {

                        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
                        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                projection, null, null, null);
                        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                        cursor.moveToLast();
                        videopath= cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                        messageText.setText("Uploading file path :"+ videopath);
                        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                        }
                                    });                      

                                 uploadFile(videopath);
                                 //uploadFile(path);

                            }
                          }).start(); 
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

and manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test333"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   < <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat Error

```
10-04 08:21:42.549: E/AndroidRuntime(874): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 08:21:42.549: E/AndroidRuntime(874): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/video/media cmp=com.android.music/.VideoBrowserActivity } from ProcessRecord{41c469c8 874:com.example.test333/u0a10039} (pid=874, uid=10039) not exported from uid 10019
10-04 08:21:42.549:

E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
10-04 08:21:42.549: E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
10-04 08:21:42.549:

 E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1947)
10-04 08:21:42.549:

 E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
10-04 08:21:42.549: 

E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
10-04 08:21:42.549: 

E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
10-04 08:21:42.549: E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at com.example.test333.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
10-04 08:21:42.549: 

E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-04 08:21:42.549: E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-04 08:21:42.549:

 E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-04 08:21:42.549:


E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-04 08:21:42.549:

E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 08:21:42.549: E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-04 08:21:42.549:

E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 08:21:42.549:

E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-04 08:21:42.549: 

E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-04 08:21:42.549: 

E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-04 08:21:42.549: E/AndroidRuntime(874):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Help me sort out thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that `VideoBrowserActivity` is not exported from `com.android.music`. [That is indeed the case in the source code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml), so this appears to be a bug in Android. I have filed [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60725) about it.

Comment: what is solution for it ?

Comment: @sunil: Don't use that `Intent`. You will have to create your own video browsing activity, unfortunately.

Comment: any related code for browsing the video in other way suggest plz?

Comment: Thanks I will try the other way, but android developer should be think about this why have such a bug they are highly reputed Google developer.

Comment: @sunil: On what device were you testing your code? I have tried doing this on a Nexus 4 and a Nexus 7 (2013) and did not crash. While the source code shows the change, it may not be rolled out to many devices at the moment.

Comment: @berserk: There has been no activity. I updated the issue pointing out other activities in that app that have the same problem.